# Delete the Certain number of Rows from Postgresql table

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql, I have inserted 5000 rows in my table but I just want to delete the 1500 rows from 5000 rows. Here I don't have any constraint to delete those rows. I have to delete the top or bottom 1500 rows from the table.

I have googled a lot but I have not get any clue to delete the rows without any constraint.

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: There is no internal order in a Postgres database.  You should delete 1500 records with regard to some column order.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "bottom 1500 rows" in a relational database.

Answer (score 5):

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE ctid IN (
SELECT ctid
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY timestamp
LIMIT 1500
)
```

ctid is:
The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify logical rows.

Comment: Note that `ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM ... LIMIT n)` is awfully slow. The following runs _way_ faster: `ctid = ANY(ARRAY(SELECT ctid FROM ... LIMIT n))`